# Need IIS rewrite rule for multiple WordPress in sub-directories or for WordPress multi-site virtual sub-directories to root directories

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, web-config, multisite

I want all WordPress installed in multiple directories in root website to rewrite like following
example: `http://www.example.com/wordpress1/*` and `http://www.example.com/wordpress2/*` to `http://www.example.com/*` which excludes `wp-admin` directories and all. 
Admin URL should be same as original :`http://www.example.com/wordpress1/wp-admin/`
I am using IIS10.

or rewrite rule for WordPress Multi-site with Sub-directory option like : `http://www.example.com/wordpress1/*` &  `http://www.example.com/wordpress2/*` to `http://www.example.com/*` will work with same exemptions.

I will be using a plugin to convert categories into subdomain, so if i use subdomain based WP multi site then there will be 3rd level domain name. example : `http://category.subdomain.domain.com`
But i want it to be 2nd level `http://category.domain.com` .

Currently my url is `http://category.domain.com/subdomain`
I want to remove that `/subdomain` part. that’s all.

Comment: Then you might want to learn IIS URL Rewrite module and create a few rules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: used every thing , but now i think its beyond my capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed a way to do it just by following [this tutorial](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/) and adding a conditional function to redirect to exact directory by domain name using $_SERVER .

Answer (score 0):

Please try this rewrite rule. Thie rule will rewrite http://www.example.com/wordpress1/* and http://www.example.com/wordpress2/* to http://www.example.com/* and exclude the URL with wp-admin.

```
  <rule name="rewrite rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/[^/]+/(.*)" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="wp-admin" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" />
                </rule>
```

Comment: when i put it in web.config :403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
when i put it in web.config and also change Wordpress site url to www.example.com: 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Comment: @Dipayan. Are you sure the target URL is your expected URL? I mean you can access the target URL can be accessed directly? Or do you mean that you need something like friendlyURL?